# how to create a query in mybatis_dynamic_sql for TO_CHAR(USE_BY_DATE - ?,'YYYYMMDD') >=TRUNC(SYSDATE)

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-generator

I want to achieve the below sql query in mybatis_dynamic_sql.

```
select * from xyz where TO_CHAR(some_date_col - ?,'YYYYMMDD') >=TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use a `mapper.xml`, your `select` could look like the following. please take care, to not declare a specific `paramterType`:

```
<select
    id="myQueryInXml"
    resultType="[replace with your type]"
    resultMap="[replace with the name of your resultMap]">
    select * from ${tabName} where TO_CHAR(${colName} - #{paramName},'YYYYMMDD') >=TRUNC(SYSDATE)
</select>
```

the corresponding `Interface`-method could look like this

```
boolean myQueryInXml(
        @Param("colName") final String colName,
        @Param("tabName") final String tabName, 
        @Param("paramName") final String paramName
        );
```

if you use annotations, your `Interface`-method could look like this

```
@Select("select * from ${tabName} where TO_CHAR(${colName} - #{paramName},'YYYYMMDD') >=TRUNC(SYSDATE)")
boolean myQuery(
        @Param("colName") final String colName,
        @Param("tabName") final String tabName, 
        @Param("paramName") final String paramName
        );
```

explanation

`@Param("[replace with a parameter-name]")` makes the passed parameter available under the given name in the annotation

`$` in `mapper.xml` or (for example) `@Select("[query]")`-annotation tells myBatis to print/use the plain parameter-content. on the other hand, `#` tells myBatis to 'guess' the database type. `String`s, for example, become edged in `''` automatically. so there is no need to do it manually

please also take a look at:

[mybatis – MyBatis 3 | Mapper XML Files](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html)

[mybatis – MyBatis 3 | Dynamic SQL](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html)